# Realm SyncUser.authenticate failed with Google's clientID and Facebook

Tags: realm, swift3

I'm using Google for authenticating, like following:

```
let credential = Credential.google(token: "<SOME-HASH-HERE>.apps.googleusercontent.com")
SyncUser.authenticate(with: credential, server: serverURL, timeout: 60) { [weak self] user, error in
    guard nil == error else {
        print("error while authenticating: \(error!)")
        return
    }
    …
}
```

It gives an error 400. After some debugging I found more info about the problem, but still not sure what is wrong with that. So response looks like this:

```
{
  "invalid_params":[
    {
      "name":"provider",
      "reason":"Unknown provider!"
    }
  ],
  "status":400,
  "type":"https://realm.io/docs/object-server/problems/invalid-parameters",
  "title":"Your request parameters did not validate!",
  "code":601
}
```

Here is request body:

```
{
  "provider":"google",
  "app_id":"com.blabla.bla-bla-bla",
  "data":"<SOME-HASH-HERE>.apps.googleusercontent.com"
}
```

I took auth code from example from official documentation, and I'm using latest Realm framework.

I also checked authentication using Facebook, but it gives same error.

I checked configuration.yml file on server, and did uncomment `google` and `facebook`, put required details, and restart system. Not helping.

Does anyone experience same problem?

PS: configuration.yml(only part with `providers`):

```
# Realm Object Server Configuration
#
# For each possible setting, the commented out values are the default values
# unless another default is mentioned explicitly.
#
# Paths specified in this file can be either absolute or relative.
# Relative paths are relative to the current working directory.

  providers:
    ## Providers of authentication tokens. Each provider has a configuration
    ## object associated with it. If a provider is included here and its
    ## configuration is valid, it will be enabled.

    ## Possible providers: cloudkit, debug, facebook, realm, password
    ## Providers 'realm' and 'password' are always enabled:
    ## - The 'realm' provider is used to derive access tokens from a refresh token.
    ## - The 'password' provider is required for the dashboard to work. It supports
    ##   authentication through username/password and uses a PBKDF2 implementation.

    ## This enables authentication via a Google Sign-In access token for a
    ## specific app.
    google:
      ## The client ID as retrieved when setting up the app in the Google
      ## Developer Console.
      clientId: '<SOME-HASH-HERE>.apps.googleusercontent.com'

    ## This enables authentication via a Facebook access token for a specific app.
    ## This provider needs no configuration (uncommenting the next line enables it).
    facebook: {}
```

After I made changes in that file I called

```
sudo service realm-object-server restart
```

And just to be sure I also reboot system.

Comment: Please post relevant server configuration and information on how you restarted the server. Thanks

Comment: I just updated description, please have a look

Comment: Same issue on android.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is a bug in the sample `configuration.yml` file shipped with Realm Object Server which I suspect you're hitting. The `providers:` section in the configuration file should live under the `auth:` section (instead of inside the `network:` section where it lives in the shipped file). The fix is to simply move the relevant providers configuration to live under the `auth:` key.

We have a fix ready for this bug which will be part of the next release of Realm Object Server.

Here's a sample snippet showing the complete `auth:` section with the fix:

```
# Realm Object Server Configuration
#
# For each possible setting, the commented out values are the default values
# unless another default is mentioned explicitly.
#
# Paths specified in this file can be either absolute or relative.
# Relative paths are relative to the current working directory.

auth:
  ## The path to the public and private keys (in PEM format) that will be used
  ## to validate identity tokens sent by clients.
  ## These configuration options are MANDATORY.
  public_key_path: /etc/realm/token-signature.pub
  private_key_path: /etc/realm/token-signature.key

  providers:
    ## Providers of authentication tokens. Each provider has a configuration
    ## object associated with it. If a provider is included here and its
    ## configuration is valid, it will be enabled.

    ## Possible providers: cloudkit, debug, facebook, realm, password
    ## Providers 'realm' and 'password' are always enabled:
    ## - The 'realm' provider is used to derive access tokens from a refresh token.
    ## - The 'password' provider is required for the dashboard to work. It supports
    ##   authentication through username/password and uses a PBKDF2 implementation.

    ## This enables authentication via a Google Sign-In access token for a
    ## specific app.
    google:
      ## The client ID as retrieved when setting up the app in the Google
      ## Developer Console.
      clientId: '<SOME-HASH-HERE>.apps.googleusercontent.com'

    ## This enables authentication via a Facebook access token for a specific app.
    ## This provider needs no configuration (uncommenting the next line enables it).
    facebook: {}
```

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of what the configuration file should look like?

Comment: I just tried, restarted system, but this fix not helping. Error stays the same

Comment: Btw to apply any changes done to custom authenticators, restart the ROS. See https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#running-the-server