# Open configuration.yml file for realm server in order to allow Facebook authentication

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm new to realm and struggling to figure out how to authenticate with Facebook. The docs and other stack overflow questions constantly refer to editing the configuration.yml file, but I cannot find/open this file for the life of me. Where does this file exist?

Im basically trying to open this config file and uncomment the line that for facebook in the providers section as described here: [Realm SyncUser.authenticate failed with Google's clientID and Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978769/realm-syncuser-authenticate-failed-with-googles-clientid-and-facebook)

Answer (score 0):

References to configuration.yml suggest that you're looking at information about Realm Object Server 1.x. That file is not used when configuring the current versions of Realm Object Server.

I'd recommend you take a look at the section on [Facebook Authentication](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/latest/#facebook-authentication) in the Realm Object Server documentation.